# 3px overflow when displaying a PDF object

Tags: html, pdf, object

I have a pdf object and whan to embedd it into a site. Here is the html I came up with:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN">
<html style="height:100%">
    <head>
      <title>Overflow error test</title>
      <style type="text/css">
      *{
        margin: 0px;
      }
      </style>
    </head>
    <body style="height:100%">
        <object  width="100%" height="100%" type="application/pdf" data="Generics in java.pdf" id="pdf_content">     
            <p>PDF can't be viewed!</p>   
        </object> 
    </body>
</html>
```

This gives me the following result.

[image: Result]

How can I get rid of the right scrollbar? Setting margin, padding, border to 0 didn't help.

Answer (score -1):

You can solve this problem by making the `object` element a bit shorter. Just modify the `height` attribute like so:

```
<object  width="100%" height="99%" type="application/pdf" data="Generics in java.pdf" id="pdf_content">
```

Comment: with 99% I just have something missing at the end... I want it to fit!